# Which AWS services should I use for multiple small CSV file data query (cost effective way)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-athena

I have my Postgres DB with daily increasing data(approx 500 rows added per day) in following format

```
Timestamp,Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4, Val5
--------------------------------------------
1494410340000,1360,1362,1359.2,1354.2,28453
1494410340000,1360,1362,1359.2,1354.2,28453
1494410340000,1360,1362,1359.2,1354.2,28453
```

Every End of Day, I can write these data to AWS S3 as CSV file
Each CSV file contains data in above format for that day.
10May.csv, 11May.csv
12May.csv and so on.

These files will be hardly 25 KB each.

I want to store the above data in AWS and allow client to directly get filtered N number of rows

**For example:** client can request for data between ***10May 11 A.M.*** to **11May 3 P.M**

Basically I need to mimic this query on multiple CSV files:

```
select * from allcsvdata where timestamp between Ts1 and Ts2
```

Relevant things i have found so far:

1. AWS Athena -> Read csv and query then return result [min charge for
   10MB per scan :(]
2. AWS Gateway -> AWS Lambda fn -> Read file from S3
   and return result

**What would be better approach to this situation. 70% queries will require multiple days data [reading multiple csv files].**

So should I append all data in single file and use Athena ?

Or should I get an EC2 with presto?

Or Any other architecture to suit this need ?

I am open to suggestions, let me know if any other details are required?

Comment: Which architecture did you end up using? I am planning to use option 2 (lambda,s3). My main concern is cost.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use Amazon Athena, then it is certainly the simplest service -- no servers, no charge when it's idle, no charge for storage aside from what's already in Amazon S3.

Don't worry about the 10MB minimum charge. At $5/TB, and a minimum charge of 10MB, the minimum cost of a query is under $0.00005. I wouldn't complain about that!

Athena does not require your data in a single file -- it can read all files in a given path. If your data does grow in size, you could store it in a more storage-efficient format (eg gzip) because Athena charges for the amount of data read from disk, so compressed data is even cheaper.

Comment: I tried and found that Athena has some problems:
1) It stores result of every query in csv file on result folder in s3 [even for same queries]
2) It is not yet available in ASIA region, so there is data latency from US region to ASIA

Comment: You should only use Amazon Athena in the same region as where your data is stored. If your data is in one region and you use it with Amazon Athena from a different region, you will be charged for **data transfer**, which could cost you more than Athena itself. So, either put your data where you'll be using Athena, or use another solution for now.